# How do I get past this puzzle in the City of the Dead?

Tags: darksiders-2

I'm stuck on a puzzle in the City of the Dead. There is a lever in the middle of the room, to the left (if you're looking at the lever and standing in the back of the room) is a gap and a switch on the wall, to the right is a gate and a movable block behind it, and there is a large gate in front of the lever in the middle. When you pull the lever the large gate opens, and when you release it the large gate falls shut.

I've figured out how to get past the large gate using the Soul Splitter, and past it there was a Shadowbomb which I was able to use on the switch on the wall. This opened the right gate and I now have the movable block but I can't for the life of me figure out what I'm supposed to do with it to get my normal not Soul Split self to the other side of the gate. In other puzzles you could just take it up to the gate and leave it there and it'd catch so the gate wouldn't close, but that doesn't appear to be working (it just pushes the block out of the way).

Here is a picture of the room to help as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://darksidersdungeon.net/darksiders-ii-walkthrough-12/
Had a lot of trouble too :) just found this hope it helps

Comment: Hi, Anthony, can you please add the information from the link to your answer, please?  That way, if the site ever goes down or removes the information, we still have the information available.

Comment: I want to give you the accepted answer, but you need to toss the information from the link into your answer first, please :)

Answer (score 1):

you will need to use soul splitter to drag this block out  side the cage then activate the soul splitter on the block then drag the block back to inside the cage and there you are inside

Answer (score 1):

You have the gate open so we will go from there.
climb up onto the block and activate soul splitter, Death1 will go and activate the large gate with the turn-switch, switch to Death2 and have him jump off of the block and push it past the large gate. when you are on the other side of the gate you can activate/de-activate soul splitter.

Answer (score 0):

You split your soul, twist the slam bar in middle, hold B:- /switch  person' go inn room grab fire bomb/ go back out aim at the latch click (R3) and throw/ turn around grab platform pull it out jump on it split your soul on it take one green or purple twist lever / push the platform through and un split your soul/ advencher around, then at the top of stairs theres a hole to move on.